# gmap3 show address in infowindow

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a click event on my map markers to create an infowindow, i am trying to geocode the address to show inside the infowindow.

```
            click: function(marker) {
                pantoUser(lati,longi,i);
                addInfoWindow(lati,longi,name,datestring);
            }
```

I nearly have it working like so:

```
function addInfoWindow(lati,longi,name,datestring)
{
 // get address  
getAddress(lati,longi);

 // create infowindow
$('#dispatcher').gmap3(
  { action: 'addInfoWindow',
    latLng: [lati, longi],
    infowindow:{
      options:{
        content: name
      },
      events:{
        closeclick: function(infowindow, event){
          //alert('closing : ' + $(this).attr('id') + ' : ' + infowindow.getContent());
        }
      },
      apply:[
        { action:'setContent', 
          args:[
          '<span class="infowindow">' + name + '<br />' + content + '<br />' + datestring + '<span>'
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
);
```

}

and then the get address part:

```
 function getAddress(lati,longi)
{
    $("#dispatcher").gmap3({
             action:'getAddress',
             latLng: [lati, longi],
             callback:function(results){
             content = results && results[1] ? results && results[1].formatted_address : 'No Address';
         return content;
                }

       });
}
```

The problem is that the geocoded address is always one marker click behind. For example i may click on a marker in london and nothing happens. So i click it again and i get the infowindow with the address. Then i click on a marker in Manchester and i still see the london address, then i click on a marker in Liverpool and i get the Manchester address. and so on.

Can anyone spot the bug?

**UPDATED WORKING SOLUTION FROM SEAN**
Added the infowindow code in the callback

```
function addInfoWindow(lati,longi,name,datestring)
{
// get address
$("#dispatcher").gmap3({
     action:'getAddress',
     latLng: [lati, longi],
     callback:function(results){
     content = results && results[1] ? results && results[1].formatted_address : 'No Address';

// create infowindow       
$('#dispatcher').gmap3(
  { action: 'addInfoWindow',
    latLng: [lati, longi],
    infowindow:{
      options:{
        content: name
      },
      events:{
        closeclick: function(infowindow, event){
          //alert('closing : ' + $(this).attr('id') + ' : ' + infowindow.getContent());
        }
      },
      apply:[
        { action:'setContent', 
          args:[
          '<span class="infowindow">' + name + '<br />' + content + '<br />' + datestring + '<span>'
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
);

    } // end callback

 });
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look like standard Google Maps JavaScript v3 code; is the `gmap3` reference to something from jQuery? Also, something doesn't seem to be hanging together - the `getAddress` function returns `content`, but the code in your `addInfoWindow` function doesn't seem to be using the value.

But it sounds like the source of your problem may lie in the `callback` aspect of the code within the `getAddress` function; you cannot be sure that the callback will have completed when the code following that call within `addInfoWindow` runs. It sounds like the following may be happening:

1. `addInfoWindow` function is called
2. From within `addInfoWindow` the `getAddress` function is called
3. `getAddress` runs and completes quickly, returning control to the `addInfoWindow` function, but the callback has not yet run
4. The first time the code runs, the `content` has not yet been built (because the callback has not yet run), so nothing is displayed
5. Following return of the `addInfoWindow` function, the `getAddress` callback runs because the response is received, which establishes the `content`
6. `addInfoWindow` is called again, runs the same way, but this time it uses the content that was setup following the last callback, so it is using the `content` from the previous run
7. The scenario just repeats, repeats, repeats

There are some confusing parts of your question and it's a little hard to be sure without being able to add `alert` calls to the code or see the code run, but it sounds very likely that your code is following the steps I describe above or something very similar.

If it sounds like that fits your problem, the most straightforward way to get around it is to put the `InfoWindow` display code in with the callback code. That way, you know the content will have been set up, because the callback runs when the response is returned.

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for your time. I suspected the problem was on those lines.
Yes gmap3 is a jquery plugin for google maps api (http://gmap3.net/)

Comment: No problem; glad to help. I have added an additional short paragraph to my answer, since you believe what I described fits your problem. Hope it helps -